# Using nrf24L01 module with raspberry pi pico

Tags: microcontroller, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, radio-transmission

I am using the above mentioned module for pico to pico communication for a rc car.
I tried using the nrf test code:

```
import usys
import sys
import ustruct as struct
import utime
from machine import Pin, SPI
from nrf24l01 import NRF24L01
from micropython import const

# Slave pause between receiving data and checking for further packets.
_RX_POLL_DELAY = const(15)
# Slave pauses an additional _SLAVE_SEND_DELAY ms after receiving data and before
# transmitting to allow the (remote) master time to get into receive mode. The
# master may be a slow device. Value tested with Pyboard, ESP32 and ESP8266.
_SLAVE_SEND_DELAY = const(10)

if usys.platform == "pyboard":
    cfg = {"spi": 2, "miso": "Y7", "mosi": "Y8", "sck": "Y6", "csn": "Y5", "ce": "Y4"}
elif usys.platform == "esp8266":  # Hardware SPI
    cfg = {"spi": 1, "miso": 12, "mosi": 13, "sck": 14, "csn": 4, "ce": 5}
elif usys.platform == "esp32":  # Software SPI
    cfg = {"spi": -1, "miso": 32, "mosi": 33, "sck": 25, "csn": 26, "ce": 27}
elif sys.platform == "rp2":
    cfg = {"spi": 0, "miso": 4, "mosi": 7, "sck": 6, "csn": 15, "ce": 14}
else:
    raise ValueError("Unsupported platform {}".format(usys.platform))

# Addresses are in little-endian format. They correspond to big-endian
# 0xf0f0f0f0e1, 0xf0f0f0f0d2
pipes = (b"\xe1\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0", b"\xd2\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0")


def master():
    csn = Pin(cfg["csn"], mode=Pin.OUT, value=1)
    ce = Pin(cfg["ce"], mode=Pin.OUT, value=0)
    if cfg["spi"] == -1:
        spi = SPI(-1, sck=Pin(cfg["sck"]), mosi=Pin(cfg["mosi"]), miso=Pin(cfg["miso"]))
        nrf = NRF24L01(spi, csn, ce, payload_size=8)
    else:
        nrf = NRF24L01(SPI(cfg["spi"]), csn, ce, payload_size=8)

    nrf.open_tx_pipe(pipes[0])
    nrf.open_rx_pipe(1, pipes[1])
    nrf.start_listening()

    num_needed = 16
    num_successes = 0
    num_failures = 0
    led_state = 0

    print("NRF24L01 master mode, sending %d packets..." % num_needed)

    while num_successes < num_needed and num_failures < num_needed:
        # stop listening and send packet
        nrf.stop_listening()
        millis = utime.ticks_ms()
        led_state = max(1, (led_state << 1) & 0x0F)
        print("sending:", millis, led_state)
        try:
            nrf.send(struct.pack("ii", millis, led_state))
        except OSError:
            pass

        # start listening again
        nrf.start_listening()

        # wait for response, with 250ms timeout
        start_time = utime.ticks_ms()
        timeout = False
        while not nrf.any() and not timeout:
            if utime.ticks_diff(utime.ticks_ms(), start_time) > 250:
                timeout = True

        if timeout:
            print("failed, response timed out")
            num_failures += 1

        else:
            # recv packet
            (got_millis,) = struct.unpack("i", nrf.recv())

            # print response and round-trip delay
            print(
                "got response:",
                got_millis,
                "(delay",
                utime.ticks_diff(utime.ticks_ms(), got_millis),
                "ms)",
            )
            num_successes += 1

        # delay then loop
        utime.sleep_ms(250)

    print("master finished sending; successes=%d, failures=%d" % (num_successes, num_failures))


def slave():
    csn = Pin(cfg["csn"], mode=Pin.OUT, value=1)
    ce = Pin(cfg["ce"], mode=Pin.OUT, value=0)
    if cfg["spi"] == -1:
        spi = SPI(-1, sck=Pin(cfg["sck"]), mosi=Pin(cfg["mosi"]), miso=Pin(cfg["miso"]))
        nrf = NRF24L01(spi, csn, ce, payload_size=8)
    else:
        nrf = NRF24L01(SPI(cfg["spi"]), csn, ce, payload_size=8)

    nrf.open_tx_pipe(pipes[1])
    nrf.open_rx_pipe(1, pipes[0])
    nrf.start_listening()

    print("NRF24L01 slave mode, waiting for packets... (ctrl-C to stop)")

    while True:
        if nrf.any():
            while nrf.any():
                buf = nrf.recv()
                millis, led_state = struct.unpack("ii", buf)
                print("received:", millis, led_state)
                for led in leds:
                    if led_state & 1:
                        led.on()
                    else:
                        led.off()
                    led_state >>= 1
                utime.sleep_ms(_RX_POLL_DELAY)

            # Give master time to get into receive mode.
            utime.sleep_ms(_SLAVE_SEND_DELAY)
            nrf.stop_listening()
            try:
                nrf.send(struct.pack("i", millis))
            except OSError:
                pass
            print("sent response")
            nrf.start_listening()


try:
    import pyb

    leds = [pyb.LED(i + 1) for i in range(4)]
except:
    leds = []

print("NRF24L01 test module loaded")
print("NRF24L01 pinout for test:")
print("    CE on", cfg["ce"])
print("    CSN on", cfg["csn"])
print("    SCK on", cfg["sck"])
print("    MISO on", cfg["miso"])
print("    MOSI on", cfg["mosi"])
print("run nrf24l01test.slave() on slave, then nrf24l01test.master() on master")

master()
```

**but it shows the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 153, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 39, in master
  File "nrf24l01.py", line 82, in __init__
OSError: nRF24L01+ Hardware not responding
```

so please help me in figuring this problem out, i tried changing jumpers and redid the connections but it still shows the same error.

in the begining when i first tried this code the code was working but wasnot able to communicate with the other device but then this morning when i tried it again it shows hardware not responding
i tried using other modules to but the same error prevails over all of them too.

**THE LIBRARY:**

```
""" NRF24L01 driver for MicroPython
"""

# Source -
# https://github.com/micropython/micropython
# this file is from the drivers folder

from micropython import const
import utime

# nRF24L01+ registers
CONFIG = const(0x00)
EN_RXADDR = const(0x02)
SETUP_AW = const(0x03)
SETUP_RETR = const(0x04)
RF_CH = const(0x05)
RF_SETUP = const(0x06)
STATUS = const(0x07)
RX_ADDR_P0 = const(0x0A)
TX_ADDR = const(0x10)
RX_PW_P0 = const(0x11)
FIFO_STATUS = const(0x17)
DYNPD = const(0x1C)

# CONFIG register
EN_CRC = const(0x08)  # enable CRC
CRCO = const(0x04)  # CRC encoding scheme; 0=1 byte, 1=2 bytes
PWR_UP = const(0x02)  # 1=power up, 0=power down
PRIM_RX = const(0x01)  # RX/TX control; 0=PTX, 1=PRX

# RF_SETUP register
POWER_0 = const(0x00)  # -18 dBm
POWER_1 = const(0x02)  # -12 dBm
POWER_2 = const(0x04)  # -6 dBm
POWER_3 = const(0x06)  # 0 dBm
SPEED_1M = const(0x00)
SPEED_2M = const(0x08)
SPEED_250K = const(0x20)

# STATUS register
RX_DR = const(0x40)  # RX data ready; write 1 to clear
TX_DS = const(0x20)  # TX data sent; write 1 to clear
MAX_RT = const(0x10)  # max retransmits reached; write 1 to clear

# FIFO_STATUS register
RX_EMPTY = const(0x01)  # 1 if RX FIFO is empty

# constants for instructions
R_RX_PL_WID = const(0x60)  # read RX payload width
R_RX_PAYLOAD = const(0x61)  # read RX payload
W_TX_PAYLOAD = const(0xA0)  # write TX payload
FLUSH_TX = const(0xE1)  # flush TX FIFO
FLUSH_RX = const(0xE2)  # flush RX FIFO
NOP = const(0xFF)  # use to read STATUS register


class NRF24L01:
    def __init__(self, spi, cs, ce, channel=46, payload_size=16):
        assert payload_size <= 32

        self.buf = bytearray(1)

        # store the pins
        self.spi = spi
        self.cs = cs
        self.ce = ce

        # init the SPI bus and pins
        self.init_spi(4000000)

        # reset everything
        ce.init(ce.OUT, value=0)
        cs.init(cs.OUT, value=1)

        self.payload_size = payload_size
        self.pipe0_read_addr = None
        utime.sleep_ms(5)

        # set address width to 5 bytes and check for device present
        self.reg_write(SETUP_AW, 0b11)
        if self.reg_read(SETUP_AW) != 0b11:
            raise OSError("nRF24L01+ Hardware not responding")

        # disable dynamic payloads
        self.reg_write(DYNPD, 0)

        # auto retransmit delay: 1750us
        # auto retransmit count: 8
        self.reg_write(SETUP_RETR, (6 << 4) | 8)

        # set rf power and speed
        self.set_power_speed(POWER_3, SPEED_250K)  # Best for point to point links

        # init CRC
        self.set_crc(2)

        # clear status flags
        self.reg_write(STATUS, RX_DR | TX_DS | MAX_RT)

        # set channel
        self.set_channel(channel)

        # flush buffers
        self.flush_rx()
        self.flush_tx()

    def init_spi(self, baudrate):
        try:
            master = self.spi.MASTER
        except AttributeError:
            self.spi.init(baudrate=baudrate, polarity=0, phase=0)
        else:
            self.spi.init(master, baudrate=baudrate, polarity=0, phase=0)

    def reg_read(self, reg):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, reg)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf)
        self.cs(1)
        return self.buf[0]

    def reg_write_bytes(self, reg, buf):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, 0x20 | reg)
        self.spi.write(buf)
        self.cs(1)
        return self.buf[0]

    def reg_write(self, reg, value):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, 0x20 | reg)
        ret = self.buf[0]
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, value)
        self.cs(1)
        return ret

    def flush_rx(self):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, FLUSH_RX)
        self.cs(1)

    def flush_tx(self):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, FLUSH_TX)
        self.cs(1)

    # power is one of POWER_x defines; speed is one of SPEED_x defines
    def set_power_speed(self, power, speed):
        setup = self.reg_read(RF_SETUP) & 0b11010001
        self.reg_write(RF_SETUP, setup | power | speed)

    # length in bytes: 0, 1 or 2
    def set_crc(self, length):
        config = self.reg_read(CONFIG) & ~(CRCO | EN_CRC)
        if length == 0:
            pass
        elif length == 1:
            config |= EN_CRC
        else:
            config |= EN_CRC | CRCO
        self.reg_write(CONFIG, config)

    def set_channel(self, channel):
        self.reg_write(RF_CH, min(channel, 125))

    # address should be a bytes object 5 bytes long
    def open_tx_pipe(self, address):
        assert len(address) == 5
        self.reg_write_bytes(RX_ADDR_P0, address)
        self.reg_write_bytes(TX_ADDR, address)
        self.reg_write(RX_PW_P0, self.payload_size)

    # address should be a bytes object 5 bytes long
    # pipe 0 and 1 have 5 byte address
    # pipes 2-5 use same 4 most-significant bytes as pipe 1, plus 1 extra byte
    def open_rx_pipe(self, pipe_id, address):
        assert len(address) == 5
        assert 0 <= pipe_id <= 5
        if pipe_id == 0:
            self.pipe0_read_addr = address
        if pipe_id < 2:
            self.reg_write_bytes(RX_ADDR_P0 + pipe_id, address)
        else:
            self.reg_write(RX_ADDR_P0 + pipe_id, address[0])
        self.reg_write(RX_PW_P0 + pipe_id, self.payload_size)
        self.reg_write(EN_RXADDR, self.reg_read(EN_RXADDR) | (1 << pipe_id))

    def start_listening(self):
        self.reg_write(CONFIG, self.reg_read(CONFIG) | PWR_UP | PRIM_RX)
        self.reg_write(STATUS, RX_DR | TX_DS | MAX_RT)

        if self.pipe0_read_addr is not None:
            self.reg_write_bytes(RX_ADDR_P0, self.pipe0_read_addr)

        self.flush_rx()
        self.flush_tx()
        self.ce(1)
        utime.sleep_us(130)

    def stop_listening(self):
        self.ce(0)
        self.flush_tx()
        self.flush_rx()

    # returns True if any data available to recv
    def any(self):
        return not bool(self.reg_read(FIFO_STATUS) & RX_EMPTY)

    def recv(self):
        # get the data
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, R_RX_PAYLOAD)
        buf = self.spi.read(self.payload_size)
        self.cs(1)
        # clear RX ready flag
        self.reg_write(STATUS, RX_DR)

        return buf

    # blocking wait for tx complete
    def send(self, buf, timeout=500):
        self.send_start(buf)
        start = utime.ticks_ms()
        result = None
        while result is None and utime.ticks_diff(utime.ticks_ms(), start) < timeout:
            result = self.send_done()  # 1 == success, 2 == fail
        if result == 2:
            raise OSError("send failed")

    # non-blocking tx
    def send_start(self, buf):
        # power up
        self.reg_write(CONFIG, (self.reg_read(CONFIG) | PWR_UP) & ~PRIM_RX)
        utime.sleep_us(150)
        # send the data
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.readinto(self.buf, W_TX_PAYLOAD)
        self.spi.write(buf)
        if len(buf) < self.payload_size:
            self.spi.write(b"\x00" * (self.payload_size - len(buf)))  # pad out data
        self.cs(1)

        # enable the chip so it can send the data
        self.ce(1)
        utime.sleep_us(15)  # needs to be >10us
        self.ce(0)

    # returns None if send still in progress, 1 for success, 2 for fail
    def send_done(self):
        if not (self.reg_read(STATUS) & (TX_DS | MAX_RT)):
            return None  # tx not finished

        # either finished or failed: get and clear status flags, power down
        status = self.reg_write(STATUS, RX_DR | TX_DS | MAX_RT)
        self.reg_write(CONFIG, self.reg_read(CONFIG) & ~PWR_UP)
        return 1 if status & TX_DS else 2
```